# Anyone see an issue with my If?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Ive written an If in javascript that checks that the entry of a text box begins with 'at'. If the string entered **begins** with 'at' then it will run function `showInput()` and if it doesnt start with 'at' than an error message will be displayed.The ID of the textbox is "Command". My if is displayed below :

```
function validate(){

 var Command = 'at';

if( Command.indexOf('at')< 2 ){
    showInput();

}   
{

    else alert('Please enter valid AT command.');

}   
}
```

cheers all.

EDIT: Thanks so far! Ive tried all of them and no luck. So I have posted the whole document in a snippet below. Anyone see my issue (left the if as the original one)
thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    
<head lang="en">
    
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 

 </head>

<body>
 

    <!-- Header Image -->
    
<a href ="http://www.simplesolutions-uk.com" id="Email" target="_blank">
    
    <img src = "Header.png" alt="Simple Solutions Logo"/>
        
        </a>
    
    <!-- -->    
    
    <!-- Form Begin -->
    
 <form id="OTA">

     <!-- IMEI -->
     
    <label><font color=#829DBA face="Tahoma"><b>IMEI:</b></font></label>
     
        <input type="text" name="ID" id="IMEI" maxlength="15" >
     
     <!-- -->
     
     <!-- AT Command -->
     
    <label><font color=#829DBA face="Tahoma"><b>AT Command:</b></font></label>
     
        <input id="Command" type="text"> 
     
     <!-- -->  
     
     <!-- Response -->
     
    <label><font color=#829DBA face="Tahoma"><b>Response Needed ?</b></font></label>
     
        <input id="Check" type="checkbox" >
     
     <!-- -->
     
 </form>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
    
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="position:relative; left:1%; top:10px;" onclick="validate(); " ><br />
    
    <!-- This is were the final string will be displayed -->
    
    <p><font color="#829DBA" face="Tahoma"</font><span id='display'></span></p> 
    
    <!-- Copy to clipboard button -->
    
    
    
    <!-- -->
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    
<style> 
    
    body { 
        
    background-color: #424242;
        
    font-size: 119%;    
        
            }
 
</style>
    
<!-- -->

<!-- Javascipt -->
    
<script language="JavaScript">    
    
// AT Validation variable
    
function validate(){

  function validate(){

 var Command = 'at';

if( Command.indexOf('at')< 2 ){
    showInput();

}   
{

    else alert('Please enter valid AT command.');

}   
}
       


// If Validate finds 'at' within the command text box then it will run this function.
    
function showInput() {

//Var test is used to change the values of the check box. If it is ticked it will display 'T' (true) or 'F' (false), this is then inputted into the string using +test+ .
    
var test=null;
    
    var obj=document.getElementById("Check").checked;
    
    obj ? test='T' : test='F';
    
//The variable below then puts all the data entered together into a >RSP string. this is what is displayed when the submit button is pressed.
        
var message_entered = ">RSP=" +test+ ";ID=" + document.getElementById("IMEI").value + ";" + document.getElementById("Command").value + "<";
    
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered; 
        
}
        </script>
<!-- -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: But it's not in your `if`. Does it count?

Comment: it's `if () { } else { }` not `if () { } { else stuff }`

Comment: `Command.indexOf('at') < 2` This checks if `"at"` is at position 0, 1, or not in the string at all (-1) :P

Comment: Also, don't capitalize the first letter of a local variable. In other words, `var command ... ` instead of `var Command ... `.

Answer (score 6):

You should put the `else` between the `}{`.. and remove the last `}`

Answer (score 3):

More like this:

```
var Command = "at";        // presumably you actually get this from something else
validate(Command);

function validate(command) {
    if (command.indexOf('at') == 0) {
        showInput();
    } else {
        alert('Please enter valid AT command.');
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers mate, still not running as expected.. if you wouldn't mind Ive edited my question above, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You used too many brackets at the `else`, this is wrong.

```
function validate(){

    var Command = 'at';

    if( Command.indexOf('at')< 2 ){
        showInput();

    } else {
        alert('Please enter valid AT command.');
    }   
}
```